# Data parsing from text file

Tags: c++

i have encountered an issue regarding parsing values from a text file. What i am trying to do is i need to add up all the values for each specific events for all days and find the average of it. Example will be (290+370+346+325+325)/5 and (5+5+5+12)/4 based on the data in the text file.

A sample is listed below
For each line --> First event:Second event:Third event...:Total number of event:
Every new line is considered a new day.

```
3:290:61:148:2:5:
2:370:50:173:4:5:
5:346:87:131:4:
3:325:60:145:5:5:
3:325:60:145:5:12:13:7:
```

I have tried to do it myself but i have only managed to store each column in a string array  only. Sample code below. Will appreciate if you guys can help, thanks!

```
void IDS::parseBase() {
string temp = "";
int counting = 0;
int maxEvent = 0;
int noOfLines = 0;
vector<string> baseVector;


ifstream readBaseFile("Base-Data.txt");
ifstream readBaseFileAgain("Base-Data.txt");




while (getline(readBaseFile, temp)) {

    baseVector.push_back(temp);

}
readBaseFile.close();

//Fine the no. of lines
noOfLines =  baseVector.size();

//Find the no. of events
for (int i=0; i<baseVector.size(); i++)
{
    counting = count(baseVector[i].begin(), baseVector[i].end(), ':') - 1;

    if (maxEvent < counting)
    {
        maxEvent = counting;
    }

}


//Store individual events into array    
string a[maxEvent];

while (getline(readBaseFileAgain, temp)) {
    stringstream streamTemp(temp);

    for (int i=0; i<maxEvent; i++)
    {
         getline(streamTemp, temp, ':');
         a[i] += temp + "\n";


    }


}




}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
int a[maxEvent];
char c; // to hold the colon
while(streamTemp >> a[i++] >> c);
```